# How to insert the contents of a text file into the excel sheet cell by cell?

Tags: excel-2007

I have a text file with lots of 3-digit numbers delimited by space.Now I would like to place each number from the text file into each cell in the excel sheet moving row-wise. And once the
first row is filled, the numbers should be inserted in the cells of the second row.

I tried with the 'Get External Data' From Text option under Data Tab of Excel 2007. It displays a message "The file contains more data than will fit on a single worksheet". On clicking "Yes" to import data as much it fits, the numbers are displayed in each cell of a single row until the cell XFD1. Why the numbers are not displayed in the next next rows of the sheet?

Please suggest me on how to go about achieving this.

Comment: Where does this file come from? What are you trying to achieve by loading this data into Excel? Filling up row 1 means that there are over 16,384 items in the first row alone, and you want them broken down into several rows. What purpose does that serve? Can you explain the bigger picture? It will be easier to suggest a way forward.

Comment: This file is just a text file with lots of numbers I have got from an experiment. I'm trying to organize the numbers so that it is easy to interpret. In one row, only 256 numbers should get filled and the next numbers have to get filled in the next rows. Also if the Sheet1 is completely filled, then the remaining numbers have to get filled in the Sheet2. Please suggest me a solution for this.

Comment: If you want the data easy to interpret, what benefit will Excel provide over a text file? Why only 256 cells in row 1? What are you planning do ***do*** with the data once it is in Excel? You may as well keep in it a text file. Unless you can explain what benefit you expect from storing in Excel. People need a business logic to come up with workable suggestions. So, again: how do you plan on processing the data from Excel? What significance does the cell address have? If it does not have any, just keep the text file.

Answer (score 0):

swap the spaces with either:
Commas (,), Semi-colons(;) or tabs
to separate into columns

use
enter/return
to separate into rows

then open the file as CSV.